# How to make safe login script

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I am trying to make login script safe to stop hacking of my website. I am trying to use mysql_real_escape_string in my script can anyone guide me if i am wrong in this.

Here is my code

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("lib/conn.php");

?>
<?php
$email=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if ($email && $password){

$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND password= '$password' and status = '1'";

mysql_real_escape_string($email);
mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die ("didn't query");
$num = mysql_num_rows( $result );
if ($num == 1){

$_SESSION['ocer']=$email;




header("Location: admin.php"); 


    } 
    else {







header("Location: index.php?l=1");


}
}

?>
```

Comment: How where what when who exactly are you receiving that error? Is that the full error message? Does it point to any particular line in the code?

Comment: When i post a news then getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. Use PDO with bind parameter. Then you don't have to worry about injections.

mysql_real_escape_string returns the escaped string and should be used before constructing your query. Use is as so:

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

Also. Don not retrieve by password and email. retrieve password by email and validate that there the same.

Hope it helps

Here is the example:

```
session_start();
include("lib/conn.php");

//using isset to avoid warnings.
$email = isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

//check if values are not null
if ($email !== null && $password !== null){

    //escape email
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    //retrieve password by email and limit 1 result
    $query = "SELECT password FROM register WHERE email = '{$email}' and                         status = '1' LIMIT 1";

    //run query
    $result = mysql_query( $query ) or die ("didn't query");

    //validate if query run correctly
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    //fetch row
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    //validate result
    if ($row['password'] == $password){
        $_SESSION['ocer']=$email;
        header("Location: admin.php"); 
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php?l=1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.- Don't use **mysql*** functions because are deprecated, use **mysqli_*** functions or **PDO**

2.- You should use prepared statements, this is an example using **mysqli_*** functions:

```
<?php
$email=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if ($email && $password){

$query = "SELECT email, password 
          FROM register 
          WHERE email = ? 
                AND password= ? 
                AND status = '1'";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $email, $password);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $column1, $column2);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    echo "Column1: {$column1}, Column2: {$column2}";
}

?>
```